# Drilldown Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, report

Help

I am attempting to create a drill down report using report server and Visual Studio 2005.

I have been able to create a tree structure, but the original report looks like it opened a new report. (Crystal Report)
This was done by the report hiding all other data apart from the drilled data and the data title.

I can’t seem to be able to do this at the moment or  seem to find any help online to do what is needed.

Does anyone know how I can do this or know of any material online that could help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i can think of two different ways to interpret your question.  1.  you want a table in a report that, when the user clicks on a specific row, drills down into the report.  2.  you want a report that, when a user clicks on certain rows, it opens up another report that's a drill down of the data.  for option one, read my blog [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/creating-a-basic-drilldown-report-in-ssr-2005) and tell me if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks I was attempting to duplicate what Crystal Report did, but I have found that this is not needed now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which way you're asking, so I'll list both.

For all your data on a single report which is grouped you can right click on the row indicator on the table and select properties, then visibility. Inside visibility you should see a checkbox with "Display can be toggled by this item" then the dropdown will have a list of textboxes that are on the report. Just select the one you want to control the drilldown.

The alternative way is through report actions, which you create a separate report with or without parameters, and select the textbox and choose properties, goto action, select "Goto Report" then select the report to drill down to, and add your parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I was attempting to duplicate what Crystal Report did, but I have found that this is not needed now.